# SSIS & EzAPI: Calling constructor of EzDerivedColumn results in HRESULT: 0xC0048021

Tags: c#, ssis, sql-server-2012, ezapi

I encountered an issue with SSIS & EzAPI. Here's the code

```
EzPackage package = new EzPackage();
package.Name = "[Insert My Table Name]";
EzDataFlow parent = new EzDataFlow(package);
dataFlow.Name = package.Name;    

EzFlatFileCM destConn = new EzFlatFileCM(parent);
destConn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
destConn.Format = FlatFileFormat.Delimited;
destConn.ColumnDelimiter = "";
destConn.RowDelimiter = "\n";
destConn.ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow = false;
destConn.LocaleID = 127;

if (isUnicode)
    destConn.CodePage = 65001;

EzFlatFileDestination destination = new EzFlatFileDestination(parent);
destination.Connection = destConn;
destination.Overwrite = true;

/// ColumnSchema is a container for some column information
foreach (ColumnSchema col in columns)
{
    IDTSConnectionManagerFlatFileColumn100 newColumn = data.Columns.Add();
    newColumn.ColumnType = "Delimited";
    newColumn.DataType = col.Type;
    newColumn.ColumnDelimiter = IsLastColumnInArray(col ) ? "\n" : "";
    newColumn.ColumnWidth = (col.Type == DbColumnType.LongString) ? (int) Constants.LongStringLength : (int) Constants.StringLength;

    var columnName = newColumn as IDTSName100;
    if (columnName != null)
         columnName.Name = GetColumnAlias(col.Name, columns);
}

List<EzFlatFileDestination> destinations = new List<EzFlatFileDestination>();
destinations.Add(destin);

/// This line will blow up
EzDerivedColumn derivedColumn = new EzDerivedColumn(parent);
```

Error message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in EzAPI.dll

Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0048021
```

Now, here's my setup:
- I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Client SDK and made sure all the v110 DLLs are installed in both Program Files and GAC (Yes, they all say 11.0.0.0)
- I built EzAPI.dll by downloading latest source of EzAPI: https://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest. I made sure all the DLL references in the project point to 11.0.0.0 and Specific Version = true
- There are other versions of Microsoft.SqlServer.****.dll files in the GAC and program files, such as ones for v100 and v120. However these other-versioned DLLs are not used anywhere else in the program and they are not included in my program's bin folder.
- .NET version is 4.5 when building EzAPI.dll and in my project

Anyhow, I am stumped. I found articles with this error on web but they usually talk about how the there's a mismatch of DLLs or some of the DLLs not being installed but I don't see how these scenarios apply to me. Am I misusing EzDerivedColumn somehow? Well, it's hard to know because my error message is very vague.

Any help on this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Check your references. I seem to recall the project using a hint path results in ... v10 of the script component being used instead of 11. Next thing to check, if you remove your section of code for derived columns, does it build and emit packages?

Comment: I've already made sure everything is 11 in the project file. The project always builds fine. Error only comes in runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't install SSIS 2012 in the machine.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the approach described in the following link, to get more detailed information about the error message at runtime:

[Debugging a COMException during package generation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2009/08/03/debugging-a-comexception-during-package-generation.aspx)